# namedtuple: expected 1 argument, got 3

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have this basic namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple

DBInfos = namedtuple('dbname', 'dbpath', 'dbfile')
```

When I try to instantiate one with

```
d = DBInfos._make(['test', 'a/b/c', '.index.db'])
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
 d = DBInfos._make(['test', 'a/b/c', '.index.db'])
 File "<string>", line 21, in _make
TypeError: Expected 1 arguments, got 3
```

But I don't know why :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to the `namedtuple` function is incorrect. It should be:

```
DBInfos = namedtuple('DBInfos', ['dbname', 'dbpath', 'dbfile'])
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Comment: Thanks... ^^' Stupid mistake.